# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'cx_Oracle'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create an AWS Lambda function in Python to connect to an Oracle Database (for now, just a test connection). But I'm not got success to complete the flow. Every time I see this error message:

```
    {
      "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'cx_Oracle'",
      "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
    }
```

I've created a virtualenv at Ubuntu WSL, install the Oracle InstantClient on the lib folder, install cx_oracle by pip at sites-package folder, and create my lambda function at the same folder, zip everything, upload at my S3 and put to run.

Can anyone help me?

**My code:**

```
    import cx_Oracle

    # Yeah, you need this
    with open('/tmp/HOSTALIASES', 'w') as f: f.write(f'{os.uname()[1]} localhost\n')

    # Oracle away!
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        return str(
            cx_Oracle.connect(
                'username',
                'password',
                cx_Oracle.makedsn(
                    'rds.amazonaws.com', 1521, 'SOME_SID',
                )
            ).cursor().execute('SELECT 42 FROM DUAL').fetchone()
        )
```

**My sites-package folder:**
[image: folder]

** My lambda config: **
[image: lambda]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS Lambda runs with Amazon Linux, so you need the compatible library of cx_Oracle, in this case [manylinux.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/11/46857e5b9755ef1fa6b71e9325e774965b0f4f2b9aa51275ba1fe7e2c9a0/cx_Oracle-7.2.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl)

just download the whl, unzip it, and copy the .so file into your **lib** folder.

That way Lambda will recognize cx_Oracle.

The folder structure should look like this:
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuzVW.png)

Answer (score 0):

for python3.7 additional path in lambda use PYTHONPATH environment variable, and save your libs in this folder.

[image]

[image]